# UWP App - Certification Report: Disapproved

Tags: windows, windows-store-apps, windows-10, windows-dev-center

I have an application for Windows 10 (UWP App) available in the Windows Store for over 6 months and have never had any problems. I have already released more than 15 updates and I did not have any problems. Last week I released a new update, only with bug fixes and general improvements, the update was approved and was released. At the end of the week I received this message: "App Policies: 10.5.1 Privacy Policy Because your app accesses personal information, you need to supply a working link to a privacy policy in the “privacy URL” field when you submit the app."

My application is a simple application, and I do not need or use user data on either side of the application. Why does this happen?
I do not have any website, where can I publish the privacy policy of the application?

Answer (score 0):

> My application is a simple application, and I do not need or use user data on either side of the application. Why does this happen?

*Personal information includes all information or data that identifies or could be used to identify a person, or that is associated with such information or data. Examples of personal information include: name and address, phone number, biometric identifiers, location, contacts, photos, audio & video recordings, documents, SMS, email, or other text communication, screenshots, and in some cases, combined browsing history*.(from [**Windows Store Policies-5.1 Personal Information**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn764944.aspx#pol_10_5))

You can have a check if your app collects one or two of these.

> I do not have any website, where can I publish the privacy policy of the application?

I think an individual blog is fine if you have no website.

After completing your privacy items, please remember to add the URL in Dev Center(**Submission**->**Store listing**->go to the **Privacy policy URL** in the end of **Store listing** page)

Comment: My app dont collects any personal information. I have ads (Microsoft Advertising) in my app. The adds can collect personal information?